# Remove specific files from revision history

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svnsync, svndumpfilter

I am trying to remove specific files from the revision history that I did not mean to commit. Can someone provide a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use [`svndumpfilter`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svndumpfilter.html) tool. The procedure involves dumping your repository, filtering (with `svndumpfilter`) your dumpfile, and reloading the results into a new repository. See [this chapter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering) in the SVNBook for details.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the filtering repository dump with [svndumpfilter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svndumpfilter.html) there is another solution that allows you to get rid of specific files and folders in a repository. Please see the Apache Subversion FAQ entry ["How do I completely remove a file from the repository's history?"](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal).

The solution requires you to perform the following steps:

1. Setup [path-based authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) rules to **deny** read access for a *USERNAME* to the **PATHS** of the file or a folder you want to remove from repository history. Please note the plural noun **paths**. The file or folder you want to get rid of could have different names or can be located in different places across a repository history. Please consider this when setting up deny rules.
2. Create an empty repository,
3. Use [`svnsync`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnsync.html) tool to synchronize the source (i.e. the original one) repository to the target repository under account *USERNAME*. For details on repository replication with svnsync please refer to SVNBook chapter ["Repository Replication"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication).

Unlike `svndumpfilter`, `svnsync` will automatically translate copy operations with an unreadable source path into normal additions, which is useful if history involving copy operations needs to be filtered.

Answer (score -2):

You can't remove the revision history.

Comment: That's not true at all... that's the entire "raison d'etre" of the svndumpfilter utility.