# How to extract branches extending trunk from a SVN repository to a new repository with history

Tags: svn, branch, svnsync, svndumpfilter, svndump

I've googled that problem quite a bit , but didn't find what I need.

I've a repository that looks like this

```
/Project_A
  +- trunk
  +- branches
      +- Version_1
      +- Version_2
      +- 1st_Custom_version_for_customer_A
      +- 2nd_Custom_version_for_customer_A
/Project_B
  +- trunk
  +- branches
      +- Version_1
      +- Version_2
      +- 1st_Custom_version_for_customer_A
      +- 2nd_Custom_version_for_customer_A
```

The branches are offsprings of their trunks counterparts. For example for Project_A

```
Trunk ------------------------------------------------------>
Version_1   \--------->                    \
Version_2                  \--------->      \
1st_Custom_version_for_customer_A            \--------------->
```

The custom versions have a life of their own now and don't get any updates from the trunk anymore (many differences).

I need to extract only the revisions that are relevant to the customer in a new repository. That is : /Project_A/trunk till the moment where the 1st_Custom_version_for_customer_A was created. Then /Project_A/branches/1st_Custom_version_for_customer_A and /Project_A/branches/2nd_Custom_version_for_customer_A. And then the same for Project B. All in the same repository.

I've tried svnsync but could only extract /Project_A/branches/2nd_Custom_version_for_customer_A, and even though the history is good, I still see all the commit messages for other branches (which is a problem in my case).

As for svndumpfilter, if would be perfect if I had everything under "/Customer_A" from the beginning (I will work this way next time), but when the branch is a copy from another branch, then gets sometimes renamed, deleted, recrated, etc... I don't see it working properly.

Is there a tool or something that could help me get the work done here ?

Thanks

Comment: Path-based authorization feature (on server side) should help here, I think -- have you tried setting up a resticted account for `svnsync`?

Comment: @sendmoreinfo That's a really good idea and it should work. It's been a long time since I asked this question, and this "extract" has been postponed for the moment. If I get some idle time I'll try it though and will keep you updated

Comment: @sendmoreinfo It worked! It was just a pain to restrict access for this user with path-based authorization. More info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504851/remove-specific-files-from-revision-history/13720677#13720677

Comment: Hm, how do I convert a comment to an answer...

Comment: @sendmoreinfo I happen to work with Eric Bonnot, so just copy/paste your comment into an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path-based authorization feature (on server side) should help here -- have you tried setting up a resticted account for `svnsync`?

Comment: Yes this is the way to do it. THanks @sendmoreinfo